# Add United Kingdom spelling but not the keyboard

Tags: windows-10

I want spelling for UK english installed and available for programs that use the spelling API, but I don't want the extra keyboard layout. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What spelling API?

Comment: The one referred by [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ban.spellright).
By adding the language the spelling works, but I also get an additional keyboard I don't want.

Comment: Maybe you can remove it? Windows has a weird logic that assumes the user also needs the typical keyboard layout that goes with that language and not just the dic/spelling and keep the same keyboard. It should be in keyboard settings, select and expand the new language installed.

Comment: In Settings->Language I have the list of the installed languages. As far as I know, this is the setting I need to use to add spelling for a new language. Each language is added with its default keyboard. Clicking on the language I can see the list of keyboards installed for it, but when there is only one keyboard its "Remove" button is greyed out.